# Docker: Entrypoint shell script ignoring updated config file

Tags: docker, weblogic, dockerfile

I am running docker 17.03.0-ce on premise on an RHEL 7.3 64bit VM. I am pulling a weblogic 10.3.6 RHEL image and after that i modify weblogic domain config file which is required to run my application by passing the IP of the VM during docker run with the command "VM_IP=$(hostname -i)".So i have added sed command in the docker file along with server start script which replaces placeholder with VM IP in the config file. However, when the server starts, the config file seems to revert back to its original state, i.e. without the placeholder value getting replaced. I have observed that if i comment the server start script, the placeholder gets replaced with the proper. I tried executing the sed from a shell script which is the entry point and also tried running sed command from dockerfile.

Below is my docker file

```
FROM 192.168.1.1:5000/wcp_image:v6

WORKDIR /

USER root

ENV VM_IP=$vm_ip

RUN rm -rf 
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config/config.xml
COPY config.xml 
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config/
RUN chmod 777 
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config/config.xml && 
chown -R wcpuser.wcpuser 
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config/config.xml

COPY replace.sh /data/docker_setup
RUN chmod 777 /data/docker_setup/replace.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/data/docker_setup/replace.sh"]
CMD ["$VM_IP"]
```

And below is the replace.sh shell script

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config

sed -i -r "s/VM_IP/$VM_IP/g" 
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/config/config.xml
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/bin/startWebLogic.sh
```

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Update

Below is the startWeblogic.sh script from the container

```
#!/bin/sh

# WARNING: This file is created by the Configuration Wizard.
# Any changes to this script may be lost when adding extensions to this configuration.

# --- Start Functions ---

stopAll()
{
        # We separate the stop commands into a function so we are able to use the trap command in Unix (calling a function) to stop these services
        if [ "X${ALREADY_STOPPED}" != "X" ] ; then
                exit
        fi
        # STOP DERBY (only if we started it)
        if [ "${DERBY_FLAG}" = "true" ] ; then
                echo "Stopping Derby server..."
                ${WL_HOME}/common/derby/bin/stopNetworkServer.sh  >"${DOMAIN_HOME}/derbyShutdown.log" 2>&1

                echo "Derby server stopped."
        fi

        ALREADY_STOPPED="true"
}

classCaching()
{
        echo "Class caching enabled..."
        JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dlaunch.main.class=${SERVER_CLASS} -Dlaunch.class.path="${CLASSPATH}" -Dlaunch.complete=weblogic.store.internal.LockManagerImpl -cp ${WL_HOME}/server/lib/pcl2.jar"
        export JAVA_OPTIONS
        SERVER_CLASS="com.oracle.classloader.launch.Launcher"
}

# --- End Functions ---

# *************************************************************************
# This script is used to start WebLogic Server for this domain.
#
# To create your own start script for your domain, you can initialize the
# environment by calling @USERDOMAINHOME/setDomainEnv.
#
# setDomainEnv initializes or calls commEnv to initialize the following variables:
#
# BEA_HOME       - The BEA home directory of your WebLogic installation.
# JAVA_HOME      - Location of the version of Java used to start WebLogic
#                  Server.
# JAVA_VENDOR    - Vendor of the JVM (i.e. BEA, HP, IBM, Sun, etc.)
# PATH           - JDK and WebLogic directories are added to system path.
# WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH
#                - Classpath needed to start WebLogic Server.
# PATCH_CLASSPATH - Classpath used for patches
# PATCH_LIBPATH  - Library path used for patches
# PATCH_PATH     - Path used for patches
# WEBLOGIC_EXTENSION_DIRS - Extension dirs for WebLogic classpath patch
# JAVA_VM        - The java arg specifying the VM to run.  (i.e.
#                - server, -hotspot, etc.)
# USER_MEM_ARGS  - The variable to override the standard memory arguments
#                  passed to java.
# PRODUCTION_MODE - The variable that determines whether Weblogic Server is started in production mode.
# DERBY_HOME - Derby home directory.
# DERBY_CLASSPATH
#                - Classpath needed to start Derby.
#
# Other variables used in this script include:
# SERVER_NAME    - Name of the weblogic server.
# JAVA_OPTIONS   - Java command-line options for running the server. (These
#                  will be tagged on to the end of the JAVA_VM and
#                  MEM_ARGS)
# CLASS_CACHE    - Enable class caching of system classpath.
#
# For additional information, refer to "Managing Server Startup and Shutdown for Oracle WebLogic Server"
#  (http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17904_01/web.1111/e13708/overview.htm).
# *************************************************************************

umask 037


# Call setDomainEnv here.

DOMAIN_HOME="/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN"

. ${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setDomainEnv.sh $*

SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS}"

SAVE_CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}"

# Start Derby

DERBY_DEBUG_LEVEL="0"

if [ "${DERBY_FLAG}" = "true" ] ; then
        ${WL_HOME}/common/derby/bin/startNetworkServer.sh  >"${DOMAIN_HOME}/derby.log" 2>&1

fi

JAVA_OPTIONS="${SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS}"

SAVE_JAVA_OPTIONS=""

CLASSPATH="${SAVE_CLASSPATH}"

SAVE_CLASSPATH=""

trap 'stopAll' 1 2 3 15


if [ "${PRODUCTION_MODE}" = "true" ] ; then
        WLS_DISPLAY_MODE="Production"
else
        WLS_DISPLAY_MODE="Development"
fi

if [ "${WLS_USER}" != "" ] ; then
        JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.management.username=${WLS_USER}"
fi

if [ "${WLS_PW}" != "" ] ; then
        JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.management.password=${WLS_PW}"
fi

if [ "${MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH}" != "" ] ; then
        if [ "${CLASSPATH}" != "" ] ; then
                CLASSPATH="${CLASSPATH}${CLASSPATHSEP}${MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH}"
        else
                CLASSPATH="${MEDREC_WEBLOGIC_CLASSPATH}"
        fi
fi

echo "."

echo "."

echo "JAVA Memory arguments: ${MEM_ARGS}"

echo "."

echo "WLS Start Mode=${WLS_DISPLAY_MODE}"

echo "."

echo "CLASSPATH=${CLASSPATH}"

echo "."

echo "PATH=${PATH}"

echo "."

echo "***************************************************"

echo "*  To start WebLogic Server, use a username and   *"

echo "*  password assigned to an admin-level user.  For *"

echo "*  server administration, use the WebLogic Server *"

echo "*  console at http://hostname:port/console        *"

echo "***************************************************"

# CLASS CACHING

if [ "${CLASS_CACHE}" = "true" ] ; then
        classCaching
fi

# START WEBLOGIC

echo "starting weblogic with Java version:"

${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} -version

if [ "${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}" = "" ] ; then
        echo "Starting WLS with line:"
        echo "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}"
        ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
else
        echo "Redirecting output from WLS window to ${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}"
        ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WL_HOME}/server/lib/weblogic.policy ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}  >"${WLS_REDIRECT_LOG}" 2>&1
fi

stopAll

popd

# Exit this script only if we have been told to exit.

if [ "${doExitFlag}" = "true" ] ; then
        exit
fi
```

Comment: can you mention in which step of entrypoint you are starting server ? Or just paste the whole entrypoint file here. It seems you are doing something wrong. I would suggest you to put `sh serverstart.sh` in `replace.sh` after replacing the `$VM_IP`.

Comment: The last line of the shell script which i have pasted above, starts the server. Below is the line from the shell script.
/data/Oracle/Middleware/user_projects/domains/WCP_DOMAIN/bin/startWebLogic.sh

Comment: So your `startWebLogic.sh` having something which modifies the ip you have replaced. can you paste `startWebLogic.sh` here ?

Comment: Updated the question with startWebLogic.sh script.

Comment: what will this `${WL_HOME}/common/derby/bin/startNetworkServer.sh`  do ?

Comment: also `${DOMAIN_HOME}/bin/setDomainEnv.sh` this ?

Comment: `CMD ["$VM_IP"]` should be `CMD ["$$VM_IP"]`?. Also in `ENV VM_IP=$vm_ip` where is `$vm_ip` coming from?

Comment: startNetworkServer.sh is disabled, and setDomainEnv.sh sets some env variables which does not affect the domain config.xml. The CMD["$VM_IP"] is the argument passed to the entry point which is a shell script, and i think the line "VM_IP=$vm_ip" is obsolete and should be removed.